# how to send integer as a parameter

Tags: shell-script

I need to write a script in Linux.
I want to execute a function several times with a different parameter in each iteration.

I write the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash << _EOF_
for ((i=0; i<=20;i++));do
MYFUNCTION -X
done
_EOF_
```

where -X must be an integer.
I tried to write `$i` instead but without success.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Post the complete script. What happens when you run this script? Copy-paste the full output.

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: $i should work just fine... what happens if you put **echo $i** within the for loop?

Comment: Just curious why you've wrapped a bash script with a bash script?

Answer (score 8):

Lose the **heredoc** and it should work just fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0; i<=20;i++));do
    MYFUNCTION "-$i"
done
```

alternatively, you can use a **single-quoted heredoc**, which will prevent the `$i` from **being interpolated from the outside context where it isn't set**:

```
#!/bin/bash

bash << '_EOF_'
for ((i=0; i<=20;i++));do
    MYFUNCTION "-$i"
done
_EOF_
```

but there's hardly a good reason to start another bash from a freshly started bash process.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to use heredoc in this context.

The below code worked just fine with bash version 4.2.26:

```
#!/bin/bash
function f()
{
    echo $1;
};
for i in {1..20}; # This works for a range of integers, but for unrelated values, you can use "i in x y z" format
do
    f $i; 
done;
```

If you still have issues, please provide bash version and the complete code you are testing.

Comment: You can do without the function keyword. Bash isn't javascript.

Comment: Well, it is different conventions people just get used to, I guess!